# Getting value of select (dropdown) before change : using normal Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The thing i want to achieve is whenever the  dropdown is changed i want the value of the dropdown before change.i.e need to compare both previous and current value and do some action.
Lets say currently option Option3 is selected now when i change it to OPtion1 in the onchange event (ie when i changed it ) i want it's previous value ie option3 expected in this case.

How can this be achieved ?

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In the change handler, save the current value to a variable. Next time when the handler executes, you can read the old value from that variable _before_ assigning the current value to it again.

Comment: Your title says you want to use normal JS, yet you've tagged jQuery?

Comment: Try my fiddle, no offense but I answered first and has a complete explanation. Plus its native JS

Answer (score 2):

In your JS code initialize the first value of the select using global variable, or at-least can be access by your onchange function, now when the select trigger the onchange function use the global variable to compare with the current select value, after comparing update the global variable value with the current select value.

try below js:

```
<script>
var previous;
window.onload=function()
{
    previous=document.getElementById("test").value;
}
function compare(select)
{
    alert("previous:"+previous+" | current: "+select.value);
    previous=select.value;
}
</script>
```

the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/2ogm86sn/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 2 event listeners, one on focus and on on change...

```
(function () {

    var select = document.getElementById("test");

    select.addEventListener('focus', function () {

        // Here is the current value
        var curVal = this.value;

        console.log('Current Value: ' + curVal);

    });

    select.addEventListener('change', function () {

        // Here is the current value
        var newVal = this.value;

        console.log('New Value: ' + newVal);

    });

})();
```

Click here for a [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hfaeb950/)